# How to get SDDM themes working on Xubuntu?

Tags: xubuntu, themes, login-screen, qml, sddm

My problem is the following :

I'm on Xubuntu, and I use SDDM on xfce. I need to use SDDM because there is a theme I want to use on it, I've installed it in the right folder, changed SDDM.conf, and when previewing it, it work perfectly.
But whenever I restart my pc or lock my session, It show Breeze theme with the error :

```
"The current theme cannot be loaded due to the errors below. please select another theme."
"file:///usr/share/sddm/themes/sddm-lain-wired-theme-master/Main.qml: file not found."
```

Even tho Main.qml is in the right folder, what am I doing wrong ? Sorry for being a noob :c

Answer (score 0):

Probably the "file://" at the start of the file address causing this. Not sure though you have not provided any other information such as installing and testing another theme or so on and so forth.